# discord api add user to guild

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, discord

Hi I am trying to use discord api to add the user to the guild when he login. But I am getting 401 Unauthorized and I am not sure why.
This is my code:

```
  const data = new FormData();

  data.append("client_id", CLIENT_ID);
  data.append("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET);
  data.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
  data.append("redirect_uri", `http://localhost:3000/callback`);
  data.append("scope", "identify,guilds.join");
  data.append("code", req.query.code);

  var response = await fetch("https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data
  });

  const json = await response.json();

  var resp = await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/guilds/813847215058845708/members/463696108766494730`, {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Bot ${json.access_token}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
  });
```

console.log(resp)

[image]

Everything seems to be working,I can get the user avatar,name and etc. but can't add him to the guild,anyone help me,plz

Comment: Is that user a bot or a person?

Comment: it's a user that I am trying to add whe they logged in on my dashboard

Comment: Please don't tag a Discord API question with the `discord.js` tag, they are very different

Answer (score 0):

You're providing an invalid authorization header. You can't use your access token with the `bot` prefix since you're making a normal OAuth2 call. Instead you need to provide the token type returned by the Discord-API.

---

Change

```js
headers: {
    "Authorization": `Bot ${json.access_token}`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}
```

to

```js
headers: {
    authorization: `${json.token_type} ${json.access_token}`
}
```

---

Also, the way you pass your scopes seems to be incorrect as well. Try

```js
data.append("scope", "identify guilds guilds.join");
```

Comment: still the same thing

Comment: still the same thing

Comment: @BrunoGod Edited once again. If that doesn't work either, I'm out of ideas. I just tested and it worked for me.

Comment: yea the same thing again. I am not sure why this is not working for me.I know it sound weird, but could u send me ur code?